# Is it acceptable to answer questions with content copied directly from a wiki page?

Tags: discussion, answers

In the comment section of [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/190799/87290), it was suggested that the answer was downvoted because the answer came directly from a wiki page. With that in mind, is it generally acceptable to answer questions which already have detailed wiki pages covering the topic by copying that content over and formatting it as an answer?

Comment: That answer has *one* downvote and *eight* upvotes. It's probably not something worth worrying about.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, *so long as you respect the wiki's content license.*

For example, it appears to me that the answer "comes" from a previous incarnation of [this article](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Poop#Poop) from gamepedia.com, which (unlike most wikis) is licensed with [CC BY-NC-SA 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/). This license is **incompatible** with Arqade's (theirs is sharealike non-commercial; ours allows commercial reuse). Even if it was compatible, it fails to attribute the original post.

Even if the content license was the [Do What The Fuck You Want To Public License](http://www.wtfpl.net/about/), [our anti-plagiarism guidelines](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) still require you to blockquote and link to what you're quoting.

Comment: I'd like to add that quoting a paragraph or two (or a short bulletted list), and citing that source would generally fall under fair use (or similar).  Therefore, it generally wouldn't be illegal, but that still doesn't mean it's always okay.  I can't really think of an example of where it wouldn't be okay, though.